# ¿Cómo pongo el código en las preguntas de stackoverflow?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Soy nueva por aquí y me gustaría saber como tengo que poner el código (en los cuadros grises) para que me den una al problema que tengo.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la secuencia <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> pero también tienes como opciones,

seleccionar el código y usar el botón indicado en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o agregar los contenedores `<code>` y `</code>` para definir código en tu pregunta/respuesta:

> ```
> <code>
>
>    include <iostream> using namespace std; 
>     int main() {
>     int firstNumber, secondNumber, sumOfTwoNumbers;
>    return 0; 
>    } 
>
> </code>
> ```

al agregarlos se mostraría el código de esta forma:

`include  using namespace std; 
    int main() {
    int firstNumber, secondNumber, sumOfTwoNumbers;
   return 0; 
   }`

Más información:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Sería bueno incluir la liga a https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Muy buena  idea @Rubén muchas gracias!

Comment: El problema es que marcar código es *problemático*. No siempre funciona (depende de lo que haya alrededor) y no siempre las alternativas ("{}", cremillas y Ctrl-K) dan el mismo resultado. Para peor, las capacidades son distintas en comentarios y respuestas. Es un problema de UI y UX que se arrastra por años.

Answer (score 3):

Para ello debes seleccionar todo lo que quieras poner como código y pulsar en el botón '{}' o en su defecto, la combinación de teclas: **ctrl+k**

```
ejemplo de código
```

Comment: no me permite publicar codigo asi como lo hago? he probado mil combinaciones y no hay manera

Comment: Arriba tienes la solución ilustrada con imágenes @Basicmix